# Cython: Can I use cppclass instead of class and does it have any performance advantages?

Tags: class, cython

I'm just starting out with Cython and I tried to replace:

```
cdef class TestClass:
    int m_A

    def __init__(self, int a):
        self.m_A = a

    cdef void test_method(self):
        print(self.m_A)

    cdef int return_test(self):
        return 1
```

With:

```
cdef cppclass TestClassCpp:
    int m_A

    TestClass(int a):
        m_A = a

    void TestMethod():
        print(m_A)

    int ReturnTest():
        return 1
```

To test, I created a Main function that is called by a script I built to automatically compile the code.

```
cpdef int Main(str argv):
    # Declare instance of Cython class and run tests
    print("Python")
    cdef TestClass t = TestClass(1)
    t.test_method()
    print(t.return_test())

    # Declare instance of cppclass and run tests
    print("C++")
    cdef TestClassCpp* tc = new TestClass(1)
    tc.TestMethod()
    print(tc.ReturnTest())

    return 0
```

I think there is some kinda memory issue.
I am able to create an instance of the C++ class, and ReturnTest() works, but whenever I print m_A it prints out a random number, not the one that should be in m_A. This leads me to believe the problems could be either in the constructor or in accessing member variables from other methods.
I'm doing this in an effort to optimize everything I can. So I though cppclass could be faster than class, but I've got no evidnce of this.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring your particular issue: I would strongly recommend against it.

Creating a `cppclass` from within Cython (as opposed to wrapping `cppclass` created in C++) is barely documented and you're likely to run into bugs. The issue that you ran into here is one of them. There will be more.

The big advantage of using a `cdef class` is that you can interact with it from Python. With a `cdef cppclass` you can't do that, unless you then wrap it in a `cdef class` (and once you've done that we're well into the realm of "utterly pointless").

If you want to write C++ code then you're usually better writing it in C++, and then writing a minimal wrapper in Cython. Writing it in Cython means you have to understand Cython *and* C++ *and* all the places they don't quite link up.

Finally, think long and hard about what you're trying to achieve here:

- If the answer is "I'm kind of writing C++ therefore I think it will be faster" then that's nonsense/"cargo cult programming" - you can get Cython to produce efficient C or C++ code within a regular function in a regular class.
- If the answer is "I need to allocate a lot of these classes rapidly, and the reference-counting overhead from Python is becoming a problem" then this approach *might* be a solution (but there might be other options that don't use barely supported features)

---

*Side note:*

> I created a Main function that is called by a script I built to automatically compile the code.

> `cpdef int Main(str argv):`

This is also pointless. If you're calling it from a script then just use a regular `def` function. `cpdef` offers no benefit here unless it's called *extremely* frequently from Cython. `cpdef` is rarely worthwhile.

Comment: I probably explained the whole thing very poorly, I was building a trasnpiler that outputed Cython code and then compiled it. Thus, I have no  need to make the code it generates compatible with Python, since it should not be imported and used with Python. The only instance where Python is used is for the Main function, which is called by the language's "runtime". . Also, I found out that the impact of cppclass is huge: my test script took 15 sec with cdef class and 1.3 sec with cppclass. Btw, I had to figure out all by myself because the docs, as you said, on cppclass absoolutelly suck.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can do it, but as I expected, the issue is with accessing m_A.
This is due to the fact that Cython is a bit more picky than actual C++ and requires you to use `this` to access member variables or methods. So it has to be

```
print(this.m_A)
```

not

```
print(m_A)
```